# Angular - Save into two(2) models at a time

Tags: angular, laravel, api

I want to create Dynamic Menu and Sub Menu using Angular7 and getting endpoints from Laravel.

1. I to save into the two tables at the same time and also pass the id of the main_menu table into the sub_menu
2. As the data is saved into the Menu table, it will pass the id of the Menu table and pass it into the menu_id of the Sub_menu table

Laravel: Menu Controller

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'descriptions' => 'required', 
        ]);

        $mainmenu = Mainenu::create($request->all());

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Great success! New Menu Item created',
            'mainmenu' => $mainmenu
        ]);
    }
```

Laravel: SubMenu Controller

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'menu_id' => 'required',
            'parent_id' => 'required'  
        ]);

        $submenu = Submenu::create($request->all());

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Great success! New Menu Item created',
            'submenu' => $submenu
        ]);
    }
```

Angular: model

```
export class Menu {
    id: number = '';
    name: string = '';
    description : string = '';
}

export class Submenu {
    id: number = '';
    menu_id: number = '';
    parent_id : number = '';
}
```

Service.ts

```
  addMenu (mainmenu): Observable<Mainmenu> {
    return this.http.post<Mainmenu>(apiUrl, mainmenu, httpOptions).pipe(
      tap((mainmenu: Mainmenu) => console.log(`added mainmenu w/ id=${mainmenu._id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Mainmenu>('addMenu'))
    );
  }
```

I don't know how to go further in the code

I want to save into the two tables at the same time and also pass the id of the main_menu table into the sub_menu as menu_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use [observer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#observers)

first you can have the request just like this

```
id: number = '';
name: string = '';
description : string = '';
parent_id: number = ''; //If it needs to be a submenu
```

On Menu Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'descriptions' => 'required', 
    ]);

    $mainmenu = Mainmenu::create($request->except(['parent_id']));

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Great success! New Menu Item created',
        'mainmenu' => $mainmenu
    ]);
}
```

on [Observer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#observers) :

```
namespace App\Observers;

use App\Mainmenu;
use App\Submenu;

class MainmenuObserver
{
    /**
     * Handle the Mainmenu "created" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Mainmenu  $mainmenu
     * @return void
     */
    public function created(Mainmenu $mainmenu)
    {
        $submenu = Submenu::create([
            'menu_id' => $mainmenu->id,
            'parent_id' => request()->parent_id
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I achieve this from Angular

Comment: @user11352561 The only thing that you have to in Angular is add `parent_id` in the request and the observer part is needs to be done in laravel